# How would I do something like this without a synchronous error in vhdl?

Tags: vhdl

How would I do something like this without a synchronous error in vhdl?

```
process (shift_button)
  variable x : STD_LOGIC;
begin
  x := '0';
  if falling_edge(shift_button) then
    x := '1';
  end if;
  shift_button_let_go <= x;
end process;
```

Comment: Can you please define 'synchronous error'? Do you get a 'bad synchronous description error from ISE? Thats what ISE would say if you pass this code to XST ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would first read the Xilinx support article about the error you're encountering:
http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/14047.html

It basically states there is a certain template that XST expects when making synchronous design elements (note that `falling_edge()` will use the VHDL 'event attribute). I'm guessing that XST doesn't like how you are defining your clear of `shift_button_let_go` on the rising edge of `shift_button`.

You mentioned you want `shift_button_let_go` to go high for one clock cycle after `shift_button` goes low. If this is the case then you would want to use your clock in the process' sensitivity list instead of `shift_button`.

```
process (clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    shift_button_d <= shift_button;
    if (shift_button_d = '1' and shift_button = '0') then -- Falling edge detect
      shift_button_let_go <= '1';
   else 
      shift_button_let_go <= '0';
  end if;
end process;
```

**NOTE** This logic can suffer from meta stability issues if `shift_button` is not synchronous to `clk` and is not held stable for several `clk` cycles.

Comment: ERROR:Xst:827 - "C:/Xilinx/Projects/GroupProject/LFSR_FSM.vhd" line 78: Signal shift_button_let_go cannot be synthesized, bad synchronous description. The description style you are using to describe a synchronous element (register, memory, etc.) is not supported in the current software release.

I'm trying to get shift_button_let_go to pulse high for a clock cycle

Comment: As this error massages says: you are describing something, what can not be wired in the destination platform (FPGA). If you simulate your process, you will see that it won't work as expected.